# Protect against linking multiple versions of a shared library

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, ld, elf

When you use [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/), a switch from `libfoo.so.23` to `libfoo.so.24` means that libfoo's API changed in an backwards-incompatible way.

Thus, one must not link against both `libfoo.so.23` and `libfoo.so.24`.

Example:

Status quo:

- Executable `myexe` links against `libfoo.so.23` and `libbar.so.1`
- `libbar.so.1` itself also links against `libfoo.so.23`

Erroneous change:

- `libbar.so.1` upgrades to `libfoo.so.24` without incrementing its major version number

As a result, when `myexe` is invoked the dynamic linker now loads `libfoo.so.23` and `libfoo.so.24` (cf. `ldd` output) leading to one set of functions using backwards-incompatible symbols from libfoo.

How to protect against such an error?

That means: how do I tell the linker to error out in such a situation (at build-time and runtime)?

On Linux, the linker just warns about this at build time:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libfoo.so.24, needed by libbar.so.1, 
    may conflict with libfoo.so.23
```

Is it possible to turn this into an link error?

(This warning doesn't show up at runtime.)

Other linkers on other Unices don't even warn about this at build-time.

It's possible to detect such a library version mismatch at runtime with a constructor function that is executed during library loading. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FOO_VERSION 23    
int foo_version() { return FOO_VERSION; }

static void cons() __attribute__((constructor));
static void cons()
{
  fprintf(stderr, "constructing foo (%d)\n", foo_version());
  if (foo_version() != FOO_VERSION) {
    fprintf(stderr, "foo.c: FOO_VERSION %d != foo_version() %d\n",
        FOO_VERSION, foo_version());
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

But I would prefer a linker error at build-time/runtime. Ideally something that also shows up in ldd (as an error).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to turn this into an link error?

GNU ld and Gold [have](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html):

```
   --fatal-warnings
   --no-fatal-warnings
       Treat all warnings as errors.  The default behaviour can be
       restored with the option --no-fatal-warnings.
```